# Android Application crash with Application has Stopped

Tags: android, graphics, canvas, frame

My Android app compiles fine but crashed with the message Application has stopped.
What is the problem with my code?

```
#GameView.java
public class GameView extends View {
public Bitmap droid; 
public Matrix translate;
public GameView(Context context) {
super(context);
droid = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
}
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {  
canvas.drawBitmap(droid, 10, 10, null);
}

#Game.java
public class Game extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
FrameLayout view = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.graphics_holder);
view.addView(new GameView(this));
setContentView(R.layout.game);
```

LogCat

```
07-18 04:48:05.517: E/AndroidRuntime(960): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-18 04:48:05.517: E/AndroidRuntime(960): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.oop/com.example.oop.Game}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-18 04:48:05.517: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
07-18 04:48:05.517: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
07-18 04:48:05.517: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
07-18 04:48:05.517: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
07-18 04:48:05.517: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-18 04:48:05.517: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-18 04:48:05.517: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
07-18 04:48:05.517: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-18 04:48:05.517: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-18 04:48:05.517: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
07-18 04:48:05.517: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-18 04:48:05.517: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-18 04:48:05.517: E/AndroidRuntime(960): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-18 04:48:05.517: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at com.example.oop.Game.onCreate(Game.java:19)
07-18 04:48:05.517: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
07-18 04:48:05.517: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
07-18 04:48:05.517: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
07-18 04:48:05.517: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  ... 11 more
```

If I change to this it works

```
public class Game extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//      FrameLayout view = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.graphics_holder);
//      view.addView();
        setContentView(new GameView(this));
}       
}
```

But my intention is to use a frame to encapsulate what I want to display because my layout has other GUI objects to show.

My layout file game.xml

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/padding_large" >
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/graphics_holder"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" >
    </FrameLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bpm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="@dimen/padding_large" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What error are you getting?...you can look a at the log cat, and is that the whole code?

Comment: @user153398, please report back on your investigation, based on suggestions below.

Comment: Oh dear, that is far too much of the log. In log cat errors are posted in red text. Thats what your looking for. It will give a stacktrace of the exception.

Answer (score 3):

The notification "Application has Stopped" simply means you have had an unhandled exception in your code, and it must terminate. This could be anything from dividing by zero, null pointer exceptions, or trying to call an intent for an activity not in the manifest.

While it appears that your error is based on calling findViewById prior to calling setContentView, It is literally impossible to know for certain what exactly was the problem, and if that is the only problem, based on the snippet you have provided, however Log Cat (a very useful tool and part of the ADT) provides a full stacktrace of an errors that causes a Force Close (FC for short). Please review how to use Log Cat because nearly all issues you post on SO will involve people asking for your Log Cat or stack trace.

Comment: On a side note, I would say your implementation of View seems... not in the standard way of building Android layouts. That is likely a source of issue.

Comment: View looks ok, I would have used a activity, but most java programmers who just start with Android for some crazy reason think that creating activity's overloads the device :). They fail to read the basis of android.

Comment: Agreed, I was trying to point out that that style of implementation can be a source of trouble. Always good to learn how the system expects things to be done.

Comment: I see what you are saying now, I just noticed that Game is a subclass to GameView. This is just crazy. But java programmers tend to just go directly to the reference guide. And dont read the developer guide at all.

Comment: Hi, what is the standard way of building layouts?

Comment: The standard way to build a layout would be by using an XML file to define the layout in the layouts directory in resources. There are a lot of good how-to-learn Android guides out there, including Youtube bootcamp videos, I strongly recommend you learn the Android paradigm, it will save you tons of hassle in the end.

Comment: Here is a really solid bootcamp http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mf7z_mrce00&feature=list_other&playnext=1&list=SPE953C0B85B50AB62

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't the setContent be done just after the onCreate ? How does your application know which layout to look for when you all findViewById.

Comment: Or it could be what @Pyrodante is saying, missing Activity in AndroidManifest. All said and done you are getting negative marking since you are not pasting the error from logcat.

Comment: Good catch though. TBH I didn't dig into it too deeply and went with a more fundamentals answer, I have added your observation into my answer and gave you an upvote. Thanks!